# How to save an int value in a char

Tags: c, ascii

I have integers under the value of 255 and want to save them into an char array. Im experimenting with some tests:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char string[10];
    int integers[10]; //all under 255.

    int j;
    for(j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
            integers[j]=j;
    }

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
            string[i]=(char)integers[i];
    }

    printf("%s \n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the debugger to the end of the of the program the string contains the following ascii values:

"\000\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t"

**First** I dont understand why after the 006 an \a appears and at the end a \t?

**Secondly** I wonder if there is a better way to do what I am intending? Thanks

Comment: The debugger thinks that if you have an array of characters, you'll want to interpret them as characters, so it gives more familiar notations for the characters that have an alternative to the octal notation.  If you continued, you'd see `\n`, `\r`, `\v` appear too.  AFAIK, there isn't a way to make GDB treat the array as an array of tiny integers rather than characters, but I'm not that expert in GDB and this has never worried me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing are escaped representations of [ASCII](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ascii+table) characters 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 and 0x09.

0x06 is `ACK`.

0x07 is `BEL` or `\a` (alert) and simply causes the terminal to go 'ding!'

0x08 is `BS` or backspace or `\b`.

0x09 is `TAB` or `\t`.

Comment: But if that is the case is there a way to read the \a \b and \t back to integer values?

Comment: @patriques: printf("%d \n", string); Also, if you want integers and not ASCII characters, then you should use uint8_t instead of char as the type of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII characters  you're using 0-9 are non-printable characters.

The printf function is formatting them as \nnn so that they can be seen.

The ASCII character 9 is a tab character, commonly represented as `\t`
The ASCII character 8 is the backspace character, represented as `\b`
The ASCII character 7 is a bell "or alarm" character, common represented as `\a`

See http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char string[10];
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      string[i] = i;
    }
    string[9] = '\0';

    printf("%s \n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the first integer array.
You can fill directly the string array.

```
char string[11];
int i;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    string[i] = i;
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: well i thing you will overwrite 9 this way. Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. 9 will be in string[9]. When the loop exits, i = 10. So string[i] is "empty"

Answer (score 0):

use **atoi** function to convert  ascii values to integer

Comment: Yes, but that isn't what the question is asking about.

Comment: But if that is the case is there a way to read the \a \b and \t back to integer values? – patriques 1 hour ago

Comment: The `\a` notation is simply the way it is displayed; internally, it is a number (7).  You'll find that 48 gets displayed as `0` (zero), and 65 as `A` and 97 as `a`, etc (unless you're using a very unusual code set).  Plain `char` (as distinct from `signed char` or `unsigned char`) may be a signed or unsigned type; you may be able to store values from -128 to +127, or from 0 to 255.  If you want 0 to 255 reliably, use `unsigned char` explicitly.  But GDB will still display the integer values stored in any of the char types as characters when it can.